# tkinter opening a picture

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

i have tried to open a photo using the following code but have had no luck, it says the file doesnt exist and it is all in the same folder and i have looked around but nothing seems to be working

```
from tkinter import * 
import sys  
from random import *

def button1():
    novi = Toplevel()
    canvas = Canvas ( novi , width = 300, height = 200 )
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    gif1 = PhotoImage (file = 'hey')


    canvas.create_image (50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
    cancas.gif1 = gift1
mGui = Tk()
button1 = Button(mGui, text = 'hey boiz',command = button1, height = 5 , width = 20).pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably need to add the file's extension to the `file=` argument. Some operating systems hide this from you by default. For example on WIndows there's a Folder option for "`Hide extensions for known file types`". See if you can disable it so you can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the file type whether `png` or `jpg`
 `gif1 = PhotoImage (file = 'hey')` change it to `gif1 = PhotoImage (file = 'hey.gif')`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical that the file is a gif? Since the variable name is `gif1` and ["The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files (...) If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30 formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects"](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

Comment: thank you ive rejigged my code and its all working now thank you

Comment: can tick it as answer as a reference for future coders

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the file type.

```
gif1 = PhotoImage(file='hey.png')
```

Edit:

```
gif1 = PhotoImage(file='hey.gif')
canvas.create_image (50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
canvas.gif1 = gif1
```

Corrected your typos, and my half-asleep answer.

Comment: @ConnorBurton you have several typos. cancas.gif1 = gift1 should be canvas.gif1 = gif1. Also, file = 'hey.gif' it works on my screen.